# how to prove that every complex circuit is a union of simple circuits

Tags: graph-theory

I have an euler circuit in a graph, and I want to prove that in-degree=out-degree.

I know that if I can split the original circuit to simple ones, then every simple circuit has in-degree=out-degree. and the union ow all of them gives me back the original one and I finished.
how can I prove that I can split euler circuit to simple circuits?

I'll be happy also to get any other different ways to prove the first line.

Comment: Maybe it's just me not comprehending, but what do you mean by in-degree = out-degree ?  The degree of what ?  Each vertex ?  The sum of in/out degrees of some set of vertices ?

Comment: You can use induction number of edges plus number of vertices. First, find a cycle and removed and use induction hypothesis on the remaining graph.